# Tensorboard profiler tab not showing anything behind corporate firewall

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

Versions: python3.7, tensorflow 2.9.1, tensorboard 2.9.1, tensorboard-plugin-profile==2.11.2.

tb_callback is passed in as follows

```
tb_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir=path_tologdir, histogram_freq=1, profile_batch=(1,5))
model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, callbacks=[tb_callback], epochs=10, verbose=2, use_multiprocessing=True, workers=2)
```

This successfully downloads .pb files in `path_to_logdir/plugins/profile/datetime/{pb files)`
and opening `overview_page.pb` files using notepad, I can see messages that are about profiling such as 
"your program in POTENTIALLY input-bound because n% of the total step time sampled is spent on 'All Others' ..."

Therefore following assumption is made, tensorflow successfully profiles its process however tensorboard is unable to read it.

tensorboard is ran as follows

```
tensorboard --logdir path_to_logdir/ --bind_all
```

where I access it from different server. NOTE: model training and tensorboard is ran on same server.

I can see on top right dropdown "profiler" however upon clicking it shows blank page and prints following logs in server that tensorboard is running in:

```
Illegal Content-Security-Policy for script-src: 'unsafe-inline'
Illegal Content-Security-Policy for script-src-elem: 'unsafe-inline'
```

from https://github.com/tensorflow/profiler it says `Note: The TensorFlow Profiler requires access to the Internet to load the Google Chart library. Some charts and tables may be missing if you run TensorBoard entirely offline on your local machine, behind a corporate firewall, or in a datacenter.`

Is blank page expected? I've expected few charts, not all charts missing because I'm running this behind corporate firewall.

I've been searching about this for a while and also there is https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-do-i-setup-tensorboard-profiler-for-training-as-currently-is-not-working-and-not-showing-profiling-tab/7134 in tensorflow forum however there does not seem to be any answers.

Things I've tried:

- Profile using `tf.profiler.experimental.start(log path) and .stop()` -> Same problem